# Failed to initiate service connection to simulator Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I run my program, the simulater showed the progress bar and suddenly disappeared and the pop up appeared and written there

**Failed to initiate service connection to simulator**

> DTServiceHubClient failed to bless service hub for simulator iPhone 8 (81F102A0-7BDB-4A51-903B-CBC4AFFF93FB)

Comment: Same issue in Xcode 10 when trying to use **any** simulator that is setup for iOS 12: iPhone XS, iPhone XR, iPhone XS Max, and any older iOS device configured for iOS 12.

Comment: @WilliamCerniuk right dear, Apple should resolve in upcoming versions!

Comment: In my case, App was installed in the device, so I uninstalled my app and run the build again, it works.

Comment: Same issue on hackintosh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just clean & build yor project it will run fine.
If it does not help, then restart the xcode, clean & build the project.

Comment: iOS simulators using iOS 12 still stall for me under Xcode 10 / Mojave

Comment: @WilliamCerniuk right dear, Apple should resolve in upcoming versions! or they should give us suggestion to resolve issues in pop up box

Comment: macOS 10.14.3 (18D109), ios simulator 12.1. All common fixes for this don't work. I even rm -fr the simulators and recreated them...

Comment: Restarting Xcode alone was sufficient to fix the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to restart my computer.

Clean build, xcode restart, simulator restart, simulator erase content and settings... did *not* help.